# Hibernating a Debian machine?

Tags: debian, hibernate, xorg

I have a Vostro 1000, and am running Debian Squeeze. When I hibernate from GNOME, the screen bleeds before shutting down, and upon starting up it bleeds to start up.

Is this normal and expected behavior or is something going wrong in the background?

Comment: I'm not native English speaker, so that could be the problem, but what do you mean by "the screen bleeds"?

Comment: @bbaja42 starts turning colors (like what happens to colored clothes when they are washed in hot water).